# how to match postdelayed handler with real time?

Tags: android, android-handler

I set progressbar max =30000 and delayed time 100 ms for playing 30 seonds. So When I try it, I got the final time is over than 30 seconds. when I set the delayed time to 1000ms, the result is right. But when I set the time 100ms, I got 34~35 seconds that is over what I want to expect 30s. How to exactly 30 seconds when using the delayed time 100ms?

```
    private val delayChangeProgress = 100L

        binding.recordStartButton.setOnClickListener {
            onRecord(true)
            binding.recordStartButton.visibility = View.GONE
            binding.recordStopButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            recordChangeHandler.postDelayed(updateRecordProgressTask,delayChangeProgress)
            showLog("onChangeRecordPregressBar StartTime: "+ getRecordDateFormat(mContext).format(Date(System.currentTimeMillis())))
        }

    private val updateRecordProgressTask: Runnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            if(recorder!=null) {
                onChangeRecordPregressBar()
                recordChangeHandler.postDelayed(this, delayChangeProgress)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun onChangeRecordPregressBar(){
        binding.audioStartProgressBar.max = 30000
        showLog("onChangeRecordPregressBar : "+binding.audioStartProgressBar.progress)
        binding.audioStartProgressBar.progress += delayChangeProgress.toInt()
        if(binding.audioStartProgressBar.max == binding.audioStartProgressBar.progress){
            stopRecording()
            binding.audioStartProgressBar.progress=0
            recordChangeHandler.removeCallbacks(updateRecordProgressTask)
            showLog("onChangeRecordPregressBar EndTime: "+ getRecordDateFormat(mContext).format(Date(System.currentTimeMillis())))
        }
    }
```

*log when using 1000ms delayed time*

```
onChangeRecordPregressBar StartTime: 46:09
D/TAG: onChangeRecordPregressBar : 0
D/TAG: onChangeRecordPregressBar : 1000
...
D/TAG: onChangeRecordPregressBar : 28000
D/TAG: onChangeRecordPregressBar : 29000
D/TAG: onChangeRecordPregressBar EndTime: 46:39
```

*log when using 100ms delayed time*

```
onChangeRecordPregressBar StartTime: 51:55
D/TAG: onChangeRecordPregressBar : 0
D/TAG: onChangeRecordPregressBar : 100
D/TAG: onChangeRecordPregressBar : 200
...
D/TAG: onChangeRecordPregressBar : 29800
D/TAG: onChangeRecordPregressBar : 29900
D/TAG: onChangeRecordPregressBar EndTime: 52:28
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, You should not rely on time you put to `postDelayed` to update progress. It doesn't execute exactly same 100 or 1000ms you set. When you init Handler, your Handler use same `MessageQueue` with `MainThread`, so it depend on how many task or message so time you already set can increase.

You should use variable to save time to record start example `startTime` and when you call `onChangeRecordPregressBar` You should calculate duration. Try this

```
private val delayChangeProgress = 100L
private var startTime = 0L

        binding.recordStartButton.setOnClickListener {
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            onRecord(true)
            binding.recordStartButton.visibility = View.GONE
            binding.recordStopButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            recordChangeHandler.postDelayed(updateRecordProgressTask,delayChangeProgress)
            showLog("onChangeRecordPregressBar StartTime: "+ getRecordDateFormat(mContext).format(Date(System.currentTimeMillis())))
        }

    private val updateRecordProgressTask: Runnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            if(recorder!=null) {
                onChangeRecordPregressBar()
                recordChangeHandler.postDelayed(this, delayChangeProgress)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun onChangeRecordPregressBar(){
        binding.audioStartProgressBar.max = 30000
        showLog("onChangeRecordPregressBar : "+binding.audioStartProgressBar.progress)
        binding.audioStartProgressBar.progress = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
        if(binding.audioStartProgressBar.max == binding.audioStartProgressBar.progress){
            stopRecording()
            binding.audioStartProgressBar.progress=0
            recordChangeHandler.removeCallbacks(updateRecordProgressTask)
            showLog("onChangeRecordPregressBar EndTime: "+ getRecordDateFormat(mContext).format(Date(System.currentTimeMillis())))
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you, I realized that I ignored the operation time .